# Firebase-Authentication error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, http-status-code-405

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 () while doing Firebase Authentication.
Unable to redirect the page to the next page.
after clicking on the login button the page reloads but does not redirect me to the next page and in the console i am getting 405 error.

I used window.location.href to give the next page URL but does not work.

below is the code

```
document.getElementById("login").addEventListener('click', function () {
e.preventDefault();

signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
.then((userCredential) =\> {
// Signed in
const user = userCredential.user;
alert("login successfully")
window.location.href = "postLogin/viewdata.html"


})
.catch((error) =\> {
const errorCode = error.code;
const errorMessage = error.message;
});

})

const monitorAuthStateChange = ()=\>{

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) =\> {
if (user) {
const uid = user.uid;
window.alert(" you are logged in "+uid)
window.location.href = 'postLogin/viewdata.html'`

} else {

console.log('user is not valid')
}
});
}
monitorAuthStateChange();
```

Comment: Please format your code well;